# ubuntu 14.04, after ubuntu-tweak, there is no GUI

Tags: gui

When in 12.04, each time I used Ubuntu-Tweak (open Janitor tab, check all boxes, and press Clean), after reboot ... my Ubuntu is become **CLI (DOS)** mode, not in **GUI (normal)** Interface. 
 So I run what is instructed in here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and my Pangolin back normally.

After upgrade to 14.04, yesterday I re-install **Ubuntu-Tweak** in order to give it a try. and after reboot ... and the nightmare still there!

But now I really don't know what to do? 
 * Because by using **utopic**, the ubuntu said **server not found** 
 * By using **trusty**, the ubuntu said **the newest version was installed** 
 Please guide me ... how to make my Ubuntu run normally
**Thank you**

Comment: Don't really get your question if there is one. Edit your question if you consider it.

Comment: SORRY, i don't know what you mean

Comment: tried **linux-image-generic-lts-trusty**, the system also said it was the newest version also

Comment: SORRY, i'm a newbie here so i don't know how to type in appropriate format here. and I don't know how to mark it as command here

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you need to do is reboot and when Ubuntu presents the screen with all the previous installations shown, arrow down to the choice marked "previous linux versions" (or words to that effect).  You should be able to boot to a previous version which will hopefully restore your GUI interface.  Ironically you can then uninstall whatever you did that made it stop working.  I had this very experience a couple of days ago, while experimenting on one of my "Mubuntsticks" in the quest to make Netflix work correctly under Ubuntu.

Comment: reboot and choose the advance mode, and run all options (one-by-one), and all ended to a screen, which displayed: 〈br/〉Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS czgirb tty1 〈br/〉 czgirb login: 〈br/〉 Password:

Comment: help ... help ... help ... <br/> after ubuntu-tweak, reboot, and my ubuntu was in tty1 <br/> if tried to run: sudo service lightdm restart, but the answer is <br/> stop: unknown instance: <br/> stop: job failed to start <br/> please guide me